# Is there a way to hide Share Folder size status on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012, shared-folders

I'd like to hide shared folders size status in users side. The status shows like this:

[image]

And this makes users to put more data's on the shared folders instead of using dedicated place's. Is there a way to hide this from server side or users side permanently?

Comment: If you want to limit the amount of space a user can use, you should use storage quotas. See this link for more details: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc875785(v=ws.10).aspx